# How can I define more than one index-pattern for an index in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Currently it seems the name of the index pattern is also the actual pattern, so I can not have two index-patterns for the same index, e.g. if I have two date-fields that I would like to use for time-based viewing in different dashboards...

The only workaround seems to be to use different wildcarded index-patterns which still both match the same index underneath, but that feels awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  See [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3351).

You can probably use aliases, which might feel like even more of a hack...